# Repeating code execution or alternative: Python, Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I have an issue with the execution quality with the below code when trying to move emails from inbox to another folder.

```
inbox = inbox.Items
example_folder = inbox.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'example@email.com'")
for message in example_folder:
    message.Move(folder)
```

The problem is not every email will move when commanded, same happens for SenderName, Subject, and others so it's not what I'm extracting the emails by. It does work, but I need to keep executing it to catch the ones it missed.

Any suggestions to the code? If not, is there a way for me to add new code that just repeats the command automatically until i want it to stop? (once all emails have been moved).

Comment: Why do you think that not all items are moved to the folder? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: Step #1 for every solution is understanding the problem. A debugger is a valuable tool.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend using the reversed for loop instead, see [Backward iteration in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backward-iteration-in-python/) for more information on that.

Second, I'd suggest checking whether all the required items are found using the `Restrict` method. Your collection may not contain all items you expect to be moved to the folder. So, it makes sense to run the code under the debugger and compare how many items are found and moved to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying (by calling `Move`) the very collection you are iterating over, this can result in some items being skipped. Use a backward for loop from `Items.Count` down to 1.

Answer (score 0):

*You have two issues in your code, When moving items from collection best option is to start at the end and go backwards to index 0*

*for example use the [reversed() function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_reversed.asp) with the [range() function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp), Wrap the range() method inside the reversed() method*

```
for i in reversed(range(5)):
    print(i)

# or reverse using the manual way = range(start, stop, step)
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(f"{i}")
```

*The second issue is your filter, `[SenderEmailAddress]` it seems to work `EmailType = "SMTP"` but not for `ExchangeUser` try using different filter*

*Example*

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch


def move_items(inbox_folder):
    filter_by_sender = ("@SQL=" + chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail"
                        + chr(34) + " Like '%0m3r 0m3r%'")  # update 0m3r 0m3r

    items = inbox_folder.Items.Restrict(filter_by_sender)
    print(items.Count)

    if items.Count > 0:
        for i in range(items.Count, 0, -1):
            # check item class, 43 = MailItem
            if items[i].Class == 43:
                print(items[i].Subject)
                items[i].Move(inbox_folder.Folders["temp"])  # update "temp"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    move_items(inbox)
```